# how to limit the textbox input to numeric 0-10 in html

Tags: javascript, html, validation

hi i have a textbox in html and i want a user to enter the numeric values only which  will be for eg. 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and if a user enters 11 it should show an alert box showing "only 0-10 is allowed" since i am a newbie
so far i have this script

```
SCRIPT language=Javascript>

         function validateForm()
         {
             var x=document.form["tst"]["num"].value;
             var y = parseInt( x  ,  10  )
             var i=15;
             if (y>i)
             {
                 alert("Range is Between 0-10");
                 return false;
             }
         }
</script>
```

here is my textbox code,

```
  <INPUT  id="num" name="num" onkeypress="return validateForm()" size="2" maxlength="2" type="text" >
```

Comment: Why is var i=15; ? dont you need the range between 0-10?

Comment: yes sorry its my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `var i=15;` to `var i=11;`

Answer (score 6):

You could use an HTML5 input type for ease:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="10">
```

This could potentially remove the need for ghastly modal popups.

Comment: @JanDvorak I really don't care. The OP might.

Comment: +1 for "I really don't care. The OP might." thats why we have Tags

Comment: sir m need is that the user will input 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 and if he enters 11 or 22 or so on it should restrict it from doing that

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="10">
```